# Do we need to test, Is cron job running or not? or Is Health check of cron job needed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, health-monitoring

We are using a spring boot cron job which runs after every 1 hour. Do we need to test its health for checking, Is it running or not?

Comment: Maybe you can send an email after every successful run or print some logs and check them?

Comment: You can create a database record with the time of execution

Comment: Thanks @Ahmet Amasyali.. Yes, we are using LOG4J for logging, But we want to make a health check for cron automated because we have so many cron jobs that run after every hour so it's not possible to check logs every time. So we are thinking we can get mail after cron job is stopped running.

Comment: Thanks @ Somil Garg. We are already creating DB records when cron is starting but we should get alert mail if cron stops running,  we have so many cron jobs that run after every hour so it's not possible to check DB every time. So we are thinking we can get mail after cron job is stopped running.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether you *need* to test if the cron job runs, **that is for you to decide**:

- Does it matter if it doesn't run?
- Does it matter if it runs correctly?
- Do you want to be *notified*?
- (At 4am on your rostered day off?)

Assuming that you have decided that you do need to know, there are many ways to detect that the cron job has run or not.  For example:

- Have the job append messages to a log file
- Have the job write a report file
- Have the job write a record to a database
- Have the job send a message to syslog (or equivalent).

Next you need some kind of monitoring to check that the log messages have been written, etcetera, and notifying someone in an appropriate fashion.  There are lots of existing systems for doing this; e.g. Nagios, Checkmk, Remedy, etc.  Some are free.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply... @Stephen C. .......
We are using cron job for sending an email which runs after every hour. If it not running then we should get notification using Opsgenie.

What is the our thought on it?
==> We will log the time in DB when cron is started and create a service which would be registered in SecurityConfig.java, which checks the difference between last logged time and current time if its more than 2 hours then we should get alert.
Do you think this is the correct way to check the health of CRON?